# zend framework - how to save an uploaded file as blob in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, database, zend-framework, blob

i am new to zend framework. i want to know how to store an uploaded file in mysql database as blob. please help me. thanks in advance.

Comment: how would you do it if you wherent working with ZF ? shouldn't be the same ?

Comment: i haven't done it without zend framework either!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this solves your problem. [Zend/PHP: Problem uploading/downloading file to/from MySQL's BLOB field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643474/zend-php-problem-uploading-downloading-file-to-from-mysqls-blob-field)